# Member vector not maintaining elements when attempting to push from member function

Tags: c++, vector

I have a static member function that initializes an Object1, which contains a member vector of a Object2's. Object2 has a member vector of strings.

I am trying to add a series of strings to Object2's vector. Using an Object2 member function to push the string into the vector, it doesn't maintain the elements on every call to the function.

For example, inside the function, every time it pushes, it prints that the size of the vector is 1, although it should be increasing each time.

I'm wondering if there is some memory allocation problem that is creating this.

The vector is declared in the Class definition, but not initialized in the constructor.

Considering the vector is empty, its unclear to me as to whether it is necessary to initialize it in the vector, and if so, how?

```
class Object1 {
    private:
        vector<Object2> container;
}


class Object2 {
    protected:
        vector<string> container2;

    public:
        void add_string(string to_be_added)
        {
            container2.push_back(to_be_added);
            cout << container2.size(); // always prints 1
        }
}


void object1_static_member_function()
{
    Object1 obj1;

    //assume container2 is loaded with values
    for(Object2 obj2 : obj1.container)
    {
        obj2.add_string("test string");
        obj2.add_string("test string2");
        obj2.add_string("test string3");
    }
}
```

The commented line should be increasing on each run through on the same object vector, but it always is 1 (suggesting it is 0 at the start of the function, and therefore never effectively storing the new element)

EDIT: Changing the for loop to access by reference fixed the problem, thank you very much. I recognize my question was somewhat unclear, so I appreciate the commenters assistance in deciphering it

Comment: In `for(Object2 obj2 : obj1.container)`, `Object2 obj2` is a copy of an `Object2` in `obj1.container` and will be discarded as soon as the loop finishes the current iteration. This should not be causing your reported bug, but the example given is manufactured code and cannot compile, making actually diagnosing and solving your problem without guesswork impossible.

Comment: Good question.  It would help if you chose names that did not include the elements of the other object.  Naming can make code difficult or easy to understand.

Comment: I modified your code to allow to compile / execute it ,with and without using a reference when iterating on `obj1.container` see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace `for(Object2 obj2 : obj1.container)` by `for(Object2 & obj2 : obj1.container)` to not modify a copy

---

A program using a modified version of your code to show

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object2 {
    protected:
        vector<string> container2;

    public:
        void add_string(string to_be_added)
        {
            container2.push_back(to_be_added);
            cout << container2.size() << endl; // always prints 1
        }
};

class Object1 {
    public:
        Object1(int n) { container.resize(n); }
        void function();
    private:
        vector<Object2> container;
};

void Object1::function()
{
    //assume container2 is loaded with values
#ifdef REF
    for(Object2 & obj2 : container)
#else
    for(Object2 obj2 : container)
#endif
    {
        obj2.add_string("test string");
        obj2.add_string("test string2");
        obj2.add_string("test string3");
    }
}

int main()
{
  Object1 obj1(1); /// modified

  obj1.function();
  obj1.function();
}
```

Compilation and execution without the ref :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra v.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Compilation and execution with the ref :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -DREF v.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Agreed that this is probably the solution and the question is garbled, but... the reported bug was `cout << container2.size(); // always prints 1`, not  `// always prints 1, 2 or 3`

Comment: @user4581301 yes the question itself is not clear (like the code in it ^^), will see the OP reaction ;-)

Comment: Looks like the reactions is, "Ooops. That was it."

Comment: @user4581301 hehe yes visibly :-)